# What's $(\omega\cdot2)\times(\omega\cdot 2)\ldots$?

Tags: ordinals

What's $(\omega\cdot2)\times(\omega\cdot 2)$?

Then $(\omega\cdot2)\times(\omega\cdot 2)\times(\omega\cdot 2)$?

Then the limit of this sequence?

I think it's $(\omega\cdot 2)^\omega$ but have very limited experience with ordinals.  Is that even an ordinal, and is there a better way to write it?

This part of a [larger problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262004/) that I'm breaking down.  If there were any hints or comments on that, I could maybe have clarified there.

Comment: What is omega ?

Comment: @AjayMishra the first limit ordinal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number

Comment: Do you mean $\cdot$ as ordinal multiplication and $\times$ as cartesian product of their sets? Or is $\times$ also meant as ordinal multiplication?

Comment: If it's all meant to be ordinal multiplication, then most of the 2s disappear because multiplication is associative.

Comment: @Vsotvep good question... I think that clears up the issue.  Pretty sure I'm after the *cartesian product* here.  Here's what I do know:  Let $f:\omega\cdot2\mapsto1$ then I want the preimage by $f$ of every singleton in the image, to remain ordered by the orders of elements in the image.

Comment: @user334732 there is only one function from any set to $1$...

Comment: @user10354138 I used mapsto rather than to, hoping to indicate the image of every set of order $\omega\cdot 2$ is a singleton

Comment: You want the preimage of $f$ to be in the image of what..? The preimage of $f$ is just $\omega\cdot 2$....

Comment: @Vsotvep I didn't state what I wanted the preimage of the whole of $f$ (i.e. the domain) to be.  I only stated I wanted the preimage of any singleton to be of order $\omega\cdot2$.  But I ask whether, if we apply the rules I have set, $f$ is the constant function on $f$ is $(\omega\cdot2)^\omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question:

If we take the cartesian product of $\omega$ many sets $(\omega\cdot 2)$, we get the set of all sequences of the form $\langle \alpha_n\mid n\in\omega\rangle$ where every $\alpha_n\in\omega\cdot 2$. Another way to see this is as the set $^\omega(\omega\cdot 2)$ of all functions $\omega\to\omega\cdot 2$.

If we use ordinal multiplication, then $\omega\cdot 2\cdot\omega\cdot 2=\omega\cdot\omega\cdot 2=\omega^2\cdot 2$. In general for any $n\in\omega$ you will get $\omega^n\cdot 2$ after $n$ multiplications.

The limit $(\omega\cdot 2)^\omega$ then is equal to $\sup_{n\in\omega}\{\omega^n\cdot 2\}$. Note that this is equal to $\omega^\omega$, since it is indeed an upper bound, and any ordinal less than $\omega^\omega$ will be of the form $\omega^k\cdot \beta+\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\omega^k$, $\beta<\omega$ and $k\in\omega$, and cannot be an upper bound.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. What does the notation $^\omega(\omega\cdot 2)$ mean? I see it many times but not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: It means the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega\cdot 2$, as I wrote. Writing the exponent in front makes sure that it's not confused with ordinal exponentiation, which is something different. Unfortunately there are three types of exponents in set theory that are used interchangeably: ordinal exponentiation, cardinal exponentiation, and the set of functions between two sets. Usually it is clear from context which one should be used.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something just under the limit? Perhaps a set $(\omega\cdot2)^{<\omega}$ which represents *all* finitely long sequences of pairs of infinite sequences?  I'm imagining the totality of $f:\omega^k\cdot 2\mapsto\omega^{k-1}\cdot 2$.  Or is that the same as $\omega^\omega$?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you mean. Your functions do not make sense (you're using a $\mapsto$ instead of a $\to$ here, is that what you meant?) and I really feel this is becoming a strong case of [XY problem solving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/553796). Perhaps you could open a new question with a clear and mathematically correct statement of what you want, and mainly what your goal is.

Comment: yes, I meant mapsto

Comment: the linked question is the X problem!

Comment: Yes, but the linked question is first of all not *clear* and still looks like another Y.

Comment: i don't disagree with you!  But thank-you for your help.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer better now. The bit where I put $f:\omega^k\cdot 2\mapsto\omega^{k-1}\cdot 2$ just reflects your $k\in\omega$ and if $f$ bijects every $\omega\cdot2\mapsto$ to a singleton then it maps sets of the form $\omega^k\cdot2$ to $\omega^{k-1}\cdot2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95112/discussion-between-vsotvep-and-user334732).